# There is a comparison or performance table of the different uses of FlushFileBuffers and FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFFERING?

Tags: windows, winapi, io, flush

I'm about to choose using FlushFileBuffers after each write in a file or FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFFERING each time I need open the same file.

But I did not find any performance comparison table about the use of one or another option. Well, except this advice [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> If an application is performing multiple writes to disk and also needs
>   to ensure critical data is written to persistent media, the
>   application should use unbuffered I/O instead of frequently calling
>   FlushFileBuffers. To open a file for unbuffered I/O, call the
>   CreateFile function with the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING and
>   FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH flags. This prevents the file contents from
>   being cached and flushes the metadata to disk with each write.

So I'm assuming that: for an application that will write and read many times it is better not use FlushFileBuffers. But there is any comparison article, blog, forum post about the use of them? And if the file is being closed after the write? My google-fu did not get anything yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING will return noticeable speed gain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574996/using-file-flag-no-buffering-will-return-noticeable-speed-gain)

Comment: @HansPassant I've seen that question and answers. But it did not respond my question at all. I would like to find comparison about the uses of them.

Comment: Despite what MSDN says I've found FlushFileBuffers to be faster than the flag.

Comment: @paulm thanks for your comment. I've learn more since I did this question, and seems that FlushFileBuffers could be faster in some scenarios and slower in another ones. That's why comparisons would be of help. But seems this area is not usual to average Windows programmer. :)