# Why does writing to a file fail when it's opened with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING?

Tags: delphi, winapi, file-io

I'm trying to measure the effects of `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` and `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` on a sequence of writes in a file, as request in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564575/there-is-a-comparison-or-performance-table-of-the-different-uses-of-flushfilebuf). But I've found that I can't write a file with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` set.

When I use it, Delphi returns `EWriteError` with message `stream read error`.

The code used is below:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fsFSArquivoAAC: TFileStream;
  L, lastErr: Cardinal;
  R: WideString;
  hn: THandle;
begin
  hn := Windows.CreateFile( PChar('TesteAAC.AAC2'),
              GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
              FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS,
              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL  or FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH or FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 0);

  lastErr := GetLastError();

  if (lastErr <> ERROR_SUCCESS) then
  begin
    if (lastErr <> ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS ) then
    begin
      MessageDlg('Whoops, something went wrong with CreateFile!',
                  mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    end
    else
    begin
      SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);
    end;

  end;

  fsFSArquivoAAC := TFileStream.Create( hn );

  try
    R := 'BatatinhaquandoNasceEspalharamapelochao';

    // write WideString
    L := Length(R);
    fsFSArquivoAAC.WriteBuffer(L, SizeOf(integer));
    if L > 0 then
      fsFSArquivoAAC.WriteBuffer(R[1], L * SizeOf(WideChar));
  finally
    fsFSArquivoAAC.Free;
  end;
```

If you comment `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` the code works. Why?

Comment: Note that you're not handling errors correctly. You're just creating an exception object and then discarding it. You meant to use `raise`, but better yet, use `RaiseLastOSError` instead. But since lots of OS functions could get called between the time you call `CreateFile` and the time you check for failure, it's better to store the file handle in a separate variable, check it *immediately*, and *then* pass it to the constructor. And remember `try`-`finally` so you free the stream and close the file handle in case of exceptions (like `EWriteError`).

Comment: @RobKennedy Thanks for the edit. You are right. The code was not doing exception handling at all. Also, I don't wanted to complicate it as the simple code just showed the error. I hope it is better now. Still the same error thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` and `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` there are [various requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for aligning your buffers in memory, aligning your writes with disk sectors and (I think) writing in multiples of sector sizes.  You don't seem to be doing any of these things.

Comment: You probably right. Maybe I was puzzled that the error was "stream **read** error". I'm trying to verify that.

Comment: [Relevant post in Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/14/9995509.aspx) that shows same behavior but different error.