# ReadFile fails with "The parameter is incorrect error" when I change dwFlagsAndAttributes

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am writing a C++ program and have encountered a problem while using the Windows ReadFile function. I am trying to read some bytes from a file on my computer.
I want to read the file with the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`, `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` and `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flags.

This is the minimal code where I encounter the problem https://pastebin.com/HmMVkC3B

The problem seems to be the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`. When I comment out that flag everything works as expected.
Unfortunately I should use the combination of the `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` and `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flags for this project (or something equivalent).

I am using the MSVC compiler.
I would be very grateful for any sort of help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Almost immediately after posting the question I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823498/why-does-writing-to-a-file-fail-when-its-opened-with-file-flag-no-buffering) which referred me to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

When your application is using the flag `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` file access sizes must be for a number of bytes that is an integer multiple of the volume sector size which, on my computer seems to be 512.

The fixed code would look something like this: https://pastebin.com/fGUr1aGH